# Hamcrest AssertThat does not return false for condition

Tags: collections, hamcrest

I am new into the Hamcrest and Rest Assured.
Basically I need to check List collection, whether any element is not empty/null.
This code is not properly returning false although it should.

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
values.add("H");
values.add("");
MatcherAssert.assertThat(values,Matchers.not(Matchers.everyItem(Matchers.isEmptyOrNullString())));
```

Does anybody know what is wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
It solves

```
MatcherAssert.assertThat(values,not(hasItem(isEmptyOrNullString())));
```